# How to Bind the JQGrid Dynamically

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, jqgrid

I am new to JQGrid and JQUery please give me the solution?

I am developing the Sharepoint application2010 in that am using the JQGrid, i want to show the list data  in the JQGrid. for this i have the dataset, using the dataset i need to bind the JQGrid, that dataset having differnet columns.

when ever we using the Noraml asp.net  Gridview  we can give the datasource directly like below no need to mention columns, in the same way i need to develop the JQGrid.

```
<asp:Gridview runat="server" id="GvSample"/>
```

in .cs

```
GVSample.datasource=ds;
gvSample.databind();
```

please help!

Comment: Did you get the solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firs get the details about the columns and then bind.

put this in the document.ready

```
$.ajax(
    {
       type: "POST",
       url: "SomeUrl/GetColumnsAndData",
       data: "",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(result)
       {
            colD = result.colData;
            colN = result.colNames;
            colM = result.colModel;

            jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                jsonReader : {
                    cell: "",
                    id: "0"
                },
                url: 'SomeUrl/Getdata',
                datatype: 'jsonstring',
                mtype: 'POST',
                datastr : colD,
                colNames:colN,
                colModel :colM,
                pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                rowNum: 5,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                viewrecords: true
            })
       },
       error: function(x, e)
       {
            alert(x.readyState + " "+ x.status +" "+ e.msg);   
       }
    });
setTimeout(function() {$("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}); },50);
```

Comment: Thanks For reply.....but i did not under stand it, plese can you givve me the clarity

Comment: can you please try the above?

Comment: please can you say what we need to get in to 'result' in function(result). for me it showing the error

Comment: in the url, what i need to mention, iam having the data in the datatable with in the getdata mehtod which is in  defaulst.aspx.cs file, how can i access that? also   please can you say what we need to get in to 'result' in function(result). for me it showing the error

Answer (score 0):

You can see the sample of JQGrid in asp.net here. It shows how to bind data source and column to JQGrid.

http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx

Comment: Actually my requirement is, i cannot set the datafields, because the column are changed dynamically.